# Optimising error management on function typed parameter

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm having some trouble to correctly manage my errors on my webservice. They are working quite well, but I'd like to have a centralised error management which will allow to easily control the status/string returned.

For that, I have creater a parent class for all my webservices. Here is an example of the getList.
This function allows to retrieve a list of Object JSONised. It also manages the http status.

```
public ResponseEntity<String> getList(Function getFunction) {
    String retour = error;
    HttpStatus statusRetour = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    try {
        Object ret = getFunction.apply(null);
        if (ret == null || ((List) ret).size() == 0) {
            statusRetour = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
        } else {
            retour = parser.toJson(((List) ret).stream().map(s -> parser.toJson(s)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            statusRetour = HttpStatus.OK;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.error(getFunction.toString(), e);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(retour, statusRetour);
}

//Usage
return this.getList(this.getUserFactory()::getAllUsers);
```

This is working quite well. My problems is, I can't give it a function that trows Exception as a paramter with a "::" style, even if I have managed them in my function which gives me this kind of thing...

```
return this.getList(t -> {
        try {
            return this.getMetierFactory().getAllMetier(t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // some error management ?
            return null;
        }
    });
```

And I find this kinda ugly :p

Would you have any idea ? I really love the "::" syntax. It's way clearer to read and way more logic as I want my error management to be realised in my getList function.

Comment: You should add type parameters to your `Function` parameter to avoid casting. Also, just because you've found a clever way to do things doesn't necessarily make it a good way. As you've noticed yourself, exception handling causes issues, and you'll also lose readability and code sturdiness if you try to do everything by passing a function like that.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by adding type parameters. It is my understanding that Function is a standard type for passing a one parameter-one result function as a parameter.

What I don't understand is why Java is checking the throwable exception management when I pass the function as a parameter instead of doing so when I use that function.

Comment: But it's generic and you're not using generics on it. In fact, since you're not passing a parameter to it, it should be a `Supplier<List<?>>` instead of `Function`. Don't overdo it either, functional programming should be used where it *helps* you.

Comment: Missed the Supplier, will allow me some simplification. It helped me a lot. Allowed for far less repliation in my code. I guess I'll have to stick with a wrapper managing the errors to pass a non throwing method to my class.

Thx for the help